# Trusty IPV6 is disabled, but applications are still binding to IPV6 address ports

Tags: 14.04, ipv6, docker

I have set sysctl to disable ipv6:

```
vagrant@puppet:~$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-disable.conf 
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Next I have rebooted and checked that ipv6 is disabled (1 = disabled):

```
vagrant@puppet:~$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1
```

However, netstat shows that applications are still binding to ipv6 ports:

```
vagrant@puppet:~$ netstat -nalt
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
...
tcp        0      0 192.168.56.5:3389       192.168.56.1:32744      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::53378                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are disabling IPv6 on network interfaces, but that doesn't mean that the system doesn't have IPv6. If you want a system without IPv6 then you have to disable the ipv6 kernel module.

The usual disclaimer applies: disabling IPv6 usually is a bad idea. Better to learn to work with it.

Answer (score 3):

Edit `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`. In section `[server]`, put `use-ipv6=no`.